# Implementing my own XPathNavigator in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

I am looking for a C# example implementation of a class derived from Microsoft's XPathNavigator class.  Can any one point me at such an article?

As you may (or may not) know, the XmlNavigator is designed to allow one to superimpose XPath navigation on most any data model.

I have implemented my derived XPathNavigator class and it works very well.  Very well that is except for XPath expressions that search recursively, i.e. "//*".

I am pretty sure that I have a subtle bug in the Clone, MoveToFirstChild, or MoveTo overides and I thought it might help to look at another example if one exists.

Also, I am sure that I have seen magazine articles that discuss this.  My searches have proved yielded nothing.  Maybe someone remembers such an article.

Comment: So what is the question? I don't see one.

Comment: If you could rephrase whatever 'question' is in there, it ought to be re-opened.

Comment: @Gortok: It seems the question is: "Maybe someone remembers such an article?". This is why I provided an answer. If you could, please edit the question and re-open it, I'd appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: The question is: I am looking for a C# example implementation of a class derived from Microsoft's XPathNavigator class

Learn to read before you close something.

Comment: @Jonathan Holland: This is a statement -- not a question.

Comment: Sorry Gentlemen. I did make some comments here after the initial post, but I do not see them.  For having posed such a poor question I appreciate Dimitre's clairvoyant  answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this article by Aaron Skonnard:

"[**XPath Selections and Custom Functions, and More**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188773.aspx)",

which provides an example of a class derived from [**XPathNavigator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A bug in your implementation or the MS one? If it's the MS one then you can use [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to take a peek inside.